# Why is my data not posting to the listbox?

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms

I am taking information from a textbox on a form, then passing it through to a class through a method (Still learning.) The information that I send passes through just fine. Below in my code, I have listed them out in order of how they work.

The first step is it grabs the number that is passed through (First set of code.) Then it passes it to the class with the method, which is set up as a user control (second set of code). It goes through the steps, which then takes it to another class (third set of code) to return the value that I need inside the box. Then it goes back and is supposed to post it in the box, however, that is not the case.

I am still quite new at this and need a bit of help.

Thank you,

Jimmy Dean

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InformationBookFinal
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            accountInformation.Visible = false;
            accountStatus.Visible = false;
        }


        private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void b0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            accountInformation.Visible = true;
            accountStatus.Visible = false;
        }

        private void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            accountInformation.Visible = false;
            accountStatus.Visible = true;

        }
    }
}
```

UserControl1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InformationBookFinal.User_Control
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<Information> status = new List<Information>();
        List<Information> notes = new List<Information>();
        List<Information> info = new List<Information>();

        private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            firstNameRich.Text = string.Empty;
            lastNameRich.Text = string.Empty;
            dateOFBirthRich.Text = string.Empty;
            socialSecurityRich.Text = string.Empty;
            statusRich.Text = string.Empty;
            invalidLabel.Text = string.Empty;


            var invalidMessage = "Please enter a valid account number!";

            dataAccess db = new dataAccess();
            docRetrieval dr = new docRetrieval();
            UserControl2 lb = new UserControl2();



            int accountNum;
            if (!int.TryParse(accountNumber.Text, out accountNum))
            {
                invalidLabel.Text = invalidMessage;

            }
            else
            {
                status = db.GetStatus(accountNumber.Text);
                notes = db.GetNotes(accountNumber.Text);
                info = db.GetInfo(accountNumber.Text);

                listBox1.DataSource = status;
                listBox1.DisplayMember = "FullInfo";

                 lb.listSet(accountNumber.Text);
                //noteDisplay.DataSource = notes;
                //noteDisplay.DisplayMember = "Field17";






                if (info.Count == 0)
                {
                    invalidLabel.Text = invalidMessage;

                }
                else
                {
                    firstNameRich.Text = info[0].Field1;
                    lastNameRich.Text = info[0].Field2;
                    dateOFBirthRich.Text = info[0].Field3;
                    socialSecurityRich.Text = info[0].Field4;
                    addressText.Text = info[0].Field5;
                    cityText.Text = info[0].Field6;
                    stateText.Text = info[0].Field7;
                    zipText.Text = info[0].Field8;

                    //string path = docRetrieval.doc(accountNumber.Text);

                    //if (path == "No Document has been found!")
                    //{
                        //MessageBox.Show(path);
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{

                    //    string adjustedPath = path.Replace(@"C:\", @"\\EOJ-SOL-DEMO\c$\");
                        // pdfViewer1.src = adjustedPath;
                    //}






                }
                /*if (status.Count == 0)
                {
                    statusRich.Text = "No Status.";
                    /* No status means documents are not populating out of document management software 
                     * or the field has no number matching account number. */

                /*}
                else
                {
                    if (status[0].Field9 == "Approved")
                    {
                        statusRich.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                        statusRich.Text = status[0].Field9;
                    }
                    else if (status[0].Field9 == "Past Due")
                    {
                        statusRich.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        statusRich.Text = status[0].Field9;
                    }
                    else if (status[0].Field9 == "Pending")
                    {
                        statusRich.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
                        statusRich.Text = status[0].Field9;
                    }
                    else if (status[0].Field9 == "Denied")
                    {
                        statusRich.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                        statusRich.Text = status[0].Field9;
                    }

                }*/


            }
        }
    }
}
```

UserControl2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace InformationBookFinal.User_Control
{
    public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void listSet(string test)
        {
            List<Information> status = new List<Information>();
            dataAccess db = new dataAccess();

            status = db.GetStatus(test);
            ListBoxPeople.DataSource = status;
            ListBoxPeople.DisplayMember = "FullInfo";

        }


    }
}
```

List Information:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace InformationBookFinal
{

    public class Information
    {


        public int id { get; set; }

        public string Field1 { get; set; }

        public string Field2 { get; set; }

        public string Field3 { get; set; }

        public string Field4 { get; set; }

        public string Field5 { get; set; }

        public string Field6 { get; set; }

        public string Field7 { get; set; }

        public string Field8 { get; set; }

        public string Field9 { get; set; }

        public string Field16 { get; set; }

        public string Field17 { get; set; }

        public string errormessage { get; set; }

        public string FullInfo
        {
            get
            {

                // "John Doe (jdoe@test.com)
                return $"{Field16} {Field1} {Field2} ({Field4}) {Field9}";

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @TheGeneral The data comes back with results, but those results do not post in the listbox. The listbox stays blank. I don't think I was clear on that and I do apologize. Yes, field16 is a numeric number.

Comment: what is the structure of `Information`

Comment: I don't know if it is just a typo in the code here or in your real code, but you need a space between accountVerification and ORDER   _{accountVerification}ORDER_

Comment: @TheGeneral, I have updated the code with Information

Comment: @Steve not sure why, but I do not get any errors with it being not spaced out and returns results the same with or without space.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not in the code posted here, but in the code that creates the form where the listbox is supposed to show its content. Can you show the code where you call the _string x  = lb.listSet(accountNumber.Text);_ Are you creating a new instance of the form where the ListBoxPeople exists?

Comment: @Steve The code that displays the call is the second set of the code.

Comment: Yes, but if that code uses the wrong instance of your form then you will never see anything. How do you use and prepare the variable _lb_? How does that variable gain access to the ListBoxPeople? Is that variable an instance of a form class? If yes do you call _lb.Show/ShowDialog_ ?

Comment: @Steve I have posted the full set of the code for the listbox. I am using the variable to pass information through to the next class because without that, I am unable to pass the information to the class I am using to set the listbox. Everything passes just fine, but when it gets to posting the information to the listbox on the UserControl, after passing the `DataSource` and `DisplayMember` sections it is supposed to post, but does not. It also, does not give any errors either.

Comment: Well, fine, now we know that _lb_ is an instance of a user control. But still it is unclear how do you handle it. Where do you create that variable? How do you handle it after its creation and the call to _listSet_ Did you add it to the form container controls?

Comment: Yes, it is also on the form as a user control. I have hidden it on load, so when I click on it with a button. It opens up. Let me add whole sets for you. Give me like 3 minutes.

Comment: You are calling _lb = new UserControl2();_ this creates new instance of the user control and this instance loads in ITS ListBoxPeople all the data. Now this instance is not the same instance of the UserControl2 (that has its own instance of a ListBoxPeople) already displayed by the form. This instance is the one that you look at and of couse it is empty. You should call the _listSet_ from that instance (is it _accountStatus_? or is it _accountInformation_?) and not creating a new one that none can see,

Comment: So how would I go about setting this up?

Comment: @Steve did you want credit for the answer? basically did in the button action of the main form `accountStatus.grabStatus(accountInformation.accountNumber.Text);` which referenced this `dataAccess da = new dataAccess();
            List<Information> status = new List<Information>();
            status = da.GetStatus(accountNum);
            ListBoxPeople.DataSource = status;
            ListBoxPeople.DisplayMember = "FullInfo";`

Comment: It is better if you post your own answer to your question. Explaining what were the problem and how you have fixed it.  Also I recommend you to reduce the code in the question text to the minimal required to understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result was me just making a reference to the "User Control" that I had made, so I could hide them when I clicked on buttons.

So, when I clicked the button it would make a reference to the function I had setup inside the AccountStatus user control.

```
accountStatus.grabStatus(accountInformation.accountNumber.Text);
```

Which referenced this

```
  grabStatus(string accountNum)
  {
    dataAccess da = new dataAccess(); 
    List<Information> status = new List<Information>(); 
    status = da.GetStatus(accountNum); 
    ListBoxPeople.DataSource = status; 
    ListBoxPeople.DisplayMember = "FullInfo";
  }
```